# Voice receiver arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano, arduino-due

I have the following situation. 
 
    I would like to develop a bracelet prototype that identifies when a person is on the go and also issue a question to the person for that bracelet and get an answer, depending on the status of the response by sending a notification to a mobile app. I am interested in what Arduino technologies to use.

Comment: Do you talk about speech recognition?

Comment: that's right...

Comment: You won't do that with an Arduino. There are VR and sound playing modules that you can add to Arduino, but they're crude and bulky. You won't want that in a bracelet.  You would be better looking at the K210 and MicroPython instead.

Comment: I see, but if you were using arduino, can you tell me which components would be needed?

Comment: I only want one prototype for my course work.

Comment: Some voice recognition module (which one depends on how you want it to work). Some audio playback module (which one depends on what you want to play back). Some device that will tell you if you are "on the go" (what that is depends on your definition of "on the go"). Some device that will communicate with your mobile app (which one depends on how you want to communicate). And of course an Arduino that can coordinate the whole lot.

Comment: Is there any component to check if the body is moving?

Comment: An AVR-based Arduino is woefully underpowered for something like this. It has an 8 or 16 mHz 8 bit processor without hardware floating-point support. They are too slow, have too little memory, and too little I/O bandwidth. There are some ARM based Arduino compatible boards that might be a decent foundation for something like this, but you should probably look at using a Raspberry Pi or other platform instead.

Comment: The K210 dual core 400MHz RISC-V with embedded AI processor is really what you want. You can get them as "MAix BiT" boards with MicroPython installed on them. Easy to program (if you like Python...) and does voice recognition natively. I guess they can do audio playback too if you have a DAC attached. We can't help you with them though since they're neither Arduino hardware nor using Arduino software (though there is Maixduino to allow you to program using the Arduino IDE...)

Comment: Isn't the Sparkfun EasyVR 3 Plus Shield exactly what you want? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z5Fgraby1Rk

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt That's fine for doing the VR side of things if an Arduino is chosen, but like I said... bulky... and prototyping bulky with no prospect of shrinking it (how would you shrink that?!) is not good. Start small (though on a big board) and go from there. A MAix BiT module with built in ESP8266 could be good (if WiFi is wanted) for the final product, and a MAix BiT board for prototyping.

Comment: Instead of letting the end concept run the project into the ground due to extreme complexity, why not consider alternative user interfaces better suited for an Arduino.  OTOH, consider almost any Android phone contains the hardware you are looking for (accelerometer, microphone, speaker) and would be much smaller than an Arduino with a battery and a few shield boards mounted on it.

Comment: @DarlanCandiotto, would you be interested in a solution that does not involve voice recognition or speech play back?